# Do many UDP sockets receive faster?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

### Situation

Imagine real-time fast-pace online game server. There're two types of messages: urgent (like movement and shooting, 20 per second, small size) and normal (like chat messages, 1 per minute, big size).

I want my server to receive urgent messages separately from normal messages in order to process them faster.

Handlers of urgent and normal messages can be deployed on one physical machine or on separate.

I use UDP protocol.

### Question

As I understand, if handlers are on separate physical machines there're no problems because there're two physical network streams which are independent.

But what if handlers are on one physical machine? Should I create a separate socket for each message type or there're no way to escape problem on one physical machine?

As I understand, at hardware level there's one network buffer, where all incoming packets go from one cable so many sockets don't solve the problem because it's impossible to divide streams at hardware level. Or there can be many hardware network buffers on one physical machine?

Comment: Which type of socket? TCP or UDP?

Comment: I'd like to know for both.

Comment: Please dedicate to one type of socket, or it's inappropriate for this site due to being too broad. Reference: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplexing sockets only works for TCP, since UDP has no concept of connection and packets are treated in a unified form.

If you make multiple TCP sockets, it may make sense depending on the situation. For example, if you create a channel for small data and another for large data, they would be processed differently and large data wouldn't jam the other. (e.g. sending an image doesn't stop other urgent data)

Anyway, when designing this type of communication, you would end up building your own congestion control with UDP. This way you can prioritize the urgent packets with rescheduling. Please also consider researching for a library that handles this for you.

Comment: Is my understanding of "one hardware buffer" correct?

Comment: It depends. High end machines can have multiple hardware buffers to distribute load on cores, but it's handled by the kernel anyway.